# Why is my local shared object of flash deleted as soon as I close my swf

Tags: flash, local-shared-object

I have a swf which stores local shared object but when I close the swf it also removes the shared object from disk on my MAC (chrome/safari).

Answer (score 0):

If you perform a flush() call before closing does it still remove it? Maybe check your local storage settings and make sure nothing looks off there. (http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html). Is this the first time you've used an SO, or have you had other SO's save, just not this one? Seems like it could be a number of things possibly interfering, without knowing more...

Comment: I have used SO multiple times. What specific thing is with this is, we have two swfs on a page consuming the same SO where one writes it and exits and then other loads and reads, I see SO being deleted as soon as the the one writing it is closed.